# Dose Skorokhod metric generate a norm on Skorokhod space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, skorohod-space

$0$ is a constant RCLL function. 
So for any RCLL function $f$, we can define
$|f| = d(f,0)$,
where $d$ is the Skorokhod metric.

Is this a norm? If not, why? If yes, why can't I search anything called "Skorokhod 
 norm"?

Comment: I mean, I *totally* know what RCLL and Skorokhod mean, but you might want to explain it for others.

Comment: Basic concepts are in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g.

Comment: Addition is not continuous everywhere under the Skorokhod metric.